How to remove a symbol in my csv file with R that I don't think is on my keyboard?
How do I get R to remove the "-" symbol? This is the longer minus sign not the regular minus sign. I don't think I have that symbol on my keyboard. I tried:

Port2 <- Port %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~str_replace_all(.x, "-", "")))

And with encoding
Port2 <- Port %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~str_replace_all(.x, "-", "", encoding = "UTF-8")))

Updated - not working for me...
  mutate(across(everything(), str_replace_all("—","\u2014","")))


Do not post images of code and/or data. Instead, copy-paste the output of dput(Port) into your post. That will make it more accessible.

Depending on your operating system there are different keyboard combinations to type the em-dash character: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305172/how-to-type-a-dash-or-instead-of-a-hyphen-in-stack-exchange

Copy and paste into your code em-dash "—" or en-dash "–"; adding more variety https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Unicode

Is this supposed to be a data frame? How come you have headless columns that contain the minus sign?

You can refer to the em-dash by the unicode symbol. For example
library(stringr)
str_replace_all("—", "\u2014", "")

works for me.

Hey can you take look at the above edit. This wipes out everything

if you can share your data via dput i can take a look
